# CORs does not get enabled when using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I have spent hours trying to access a resource from a different domain.

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ which is referenced in other SO posts states that by simply using `XMLHttpRequest` in a browser that supports CORS, CORS policy should be enabled. However I am still getting 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.nczonline.net/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

When using it in Firefox 34 which according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors should be sufficient.

I am trying a simple example from http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function log(msg){
        var output = $('#output');
        output.text(output.text() + " | " + msg);
        console.log(msg);
    }

    function createCORSRequest(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
            xhr.open(method, url, true);

            log("'withCredentials' exist in xhr");
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);

            log("XDomainRequest is being used");
        } else {
            xhr = null;

            log("xhr is null");
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    function main(){
        log("Attempting to make CORS request");

        var request = createCORSRequest("get", "https://www.nczonline.net/");
        if (request){
            request.onload = function(){
                log("LOADED!");
            };

            request.send();
        }
    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        main();
    });
</script>
```

And I am getting the following output:

`Attempting to make CORS request
'withCredentials' exist in xhr
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.nczonline.net/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Trying it on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zf8ydb9v/ gives same results. Is there another lever somewhere that needs to switched on to be able to use CORS bBesides using XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 2):

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (which prevents making of CORS requests) is there for **your** security, not the security of the server: it prevents malicious scripts to access your data on other servers using your cookies.
So, if you want you can still disable it at your own risk, on **your** browser.

In Chrome/Chromium, if you want to disable the same origin policy you can start it with the --disable-web-security option:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```

Anyway, if you want it to work for your users, they will not able to make CORS requests if they have not disabled this security check in their browsers (which is discouraged if not for testing).

As noted in other answers, some servers can purposely allow this kind of requests if they believe this can be useful and not harmful for their users, and they can do this with the Access-control headers.

Moreover, if you still want to find a way to provide this kind of functionality to the users, you might make a Chrome extension, [which is not bound to the same origin policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

A common solution to this is to make the cross origin request server side, returning the result to your application. You should be careful coding this: passing the url to fetch to the server will easily cause security concerns for your server side software. But if you have to fetch the same url every time, you could hard code it server side, in PHP would look like something like this:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://your_cross_request/");
?>
```

then making an ajax request to this page (which will be from the same origin) will return the content of the remote url.

Comment: This makes it seem like CORS is not useful for production at all since we can't expect users to start their browsers with disabled security policy

Comment: This is exactly the point. CORS are disabled by default in browsers because they cause important security problems, thus relying on them in production is not possible, exception made for the chrome extensions.

Comment: @NickolayKondratyev: This answer is slightly misleading. CORS is not about browser security level. It is a protocol that enables the server to tell the browser that it is OK to fetch the data using XHR and not block it because it's cross origin. To enable CORS you need to modify the server you're fetching the data from (not always possible) and make it send CORS headers allowing your site to fetch its data. Everything else in this answer is about same-origin policy which is a related topic but is **not** CORS.

Comment: Now I am even more confused when I tried to replace my example code with `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/` (from  "https://www.nczonline.net/") as suggested by @Paul S. I did not get CORS error. But I did not start my browser with security disabled I just started firefox as usual.

Answer (score 1):

[*CORS* headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) are found in the *response* sent by the server to your *request*. If the requested page isn't sending the header, it doesn't matter what you did with the request in a stock browser, you'll get a security error

The relevant *CORS* headers look like this, the last being the most important one

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I tried opening *"nczonline.net"* and when I looked at the response headers I did not see any of these, so the server is not configured to permit being loaded in this way

If you are an administrator of that website, you may want to consider adding the required headers to your responses, perhaps being specific about permitted origins rather than using the wildcard

If you're simply trying to demo your code and want to try it with a third party, load a page which does send these headers e.g. [**developer.mozilla.org**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: Having a wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` makes a compliant user agent refuse to provide any credentials with a request after the preflight request (which gets the aforementioned headers in response). Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests